# Is phplivex a extension or plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, plugins

what is the actual difference between a extension and plugin?

eg. is phplivex a extension or plugin?

i have to know in which folder i should put it in

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the website, *PHPLiveX is a php ajax library and framework to use php with ajax*, so it is neither an extension nor a plugin.*

[**Extensions** in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php) are usually C libraries that PHP can be compiled with or that can be enabled in php.ini that provide a certain functionality. For instance [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is an extension that lets you do HTTP Request.

The term **Plugin** has no definite meaning in PHP. Existing userland libraries and frameworks can be enhanced through plugins to add functionality to them. For instance, in [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), you can write custom [plugins for Zend_Controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) to add custom behavior at runtime.