# What is the technical difference between a browser extension and a plugin?

Tags: plugins, google-chrome-extension, terminology

From a user's perspective, an extension seems to be something that you go to the Chrome Web Store to get to extend the browser's functionality, whereas a plugin is something that you have to go to an external third party's website to get to extend the browser's functionality.

From a technical or implementation perspective, what is the difference between the two? I saw a similar question here ([Is phplivex a extension or plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203721/difference-between-extension-and-plugin)) but didn't get the answer I was looking for.

I am after the difference in the way an extension or plugin is developed and deployed (if any), and if there is any overlap between the two.

Comment: What answer *are* you looking for?  That question you cited doesn't really have anything to do with yours.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought that question would give the answer to the difference between how an extension and a plugin are developed and deployed. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 6):

The words "extension" and "plugin" have lots of different (but related) meanings accross software products. These words are used interchangeably by many users (and developers). In browser extensions, they have a precise meaning, which is also visible through the UI. E.g. extensions (and apps) can be managed at `chrome://extensions/`, while plugins can be managed at `chrome://plugins/` in Google Chrome.

In Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, browser extensions refer to pieces of software that augment the browser using the browser extension APIs (see extension docs for [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/), [Opera](http://dev.opera.com/extensions/), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/)). Most of the modern browsers require extensions to be written using JavaScript. Extensions are usually platform-independent and run within a limited environment (Firefox is a notable exception to the latter). Extensions are usually deployed as a bunch of JavaScript files, other assets (HTML, CSS, media, ...) and configuration bundled in a browser-specific archive. Browser usually offer a seamless way to install the extension directly in the browser.

Plugins refer to NPAPI plugins, which are pre-compiled binaries that enhance the functionality of browsers via [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI). These plugins are invoked by inserting an `<embed>` or `<object>` tag in the document with a specific MIME-type. NPAPI plugins are OS-specific (though the source code can be platform independent) but not specific to a single browser. The capabilities of NPAPI are not constrained by the browser, so a bug in a browser plugin often have huge security implications (think of Java, Adobe Flash Player, Adobe PDF Reader). This is one of the reasons why NPAPI support is [in the process of being completely dropped from Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html). NPAPI plugins are usually installed outside the browser, e.g. via MSI installers on Windows.

As said in the introduction, "plugins" and "extensions" are used interchangeably. If you hear anyone talking about "(browser) plugins", odds are that they actually mean browser extensions.

Comment: What about PPAPI? And NaCl in general, I suppose.

Comment: @Xan NaCl is a Chrome-only technology, not specific to plugins. PPAPI is Chrome's sandboxed replacement for NPAPI, but it is not yet usable by independent developers. See http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Browser+Plugins+in+a+post-NPAPI+world

Comment: Well, OP's question is Chrome-specific. Nevertheless, good overview.